# How to resolve TypeError: Empty 'DataFrame': no numeric data to plot?

Tags: mongodb, pandas, pymongo

In MongoDB, I have a database named twitter. From the database, I was trying to extract 5 languages that were used more to tweet. And I wanted to show the result using a chart. For this, I used `pandas` and `matplotlib`. But while executing the code, it says, `TypeError: Empty 'DataFrame': no numeric data to plot`

Here is my code:

```
import pymongo
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#conect with MongoClient daemon mongod
client_con = pymongo.MongoClient()
#conect with db
mydb = client_con["twitter"]
#conect with collection
mycol = mydb["twitterCol"]
#print the records
print mycol.count()

#intiate pandas
tweets = pd.DataFrame()

tweets_data = []
tweets_data= mydb.mycol.find()

"""Next, 3 columns will be added to the tweets 
DataFrame called text, lang, and country. 
Text column contains the tweet, 
Lang column contains the language in which the 
tweet was written, 
and Country the country from which the tweet was sent.
"""

tweets['text'] = map(lambda tweet: tweet["text"], tweets_data)
tweets['lang'] = map(lambda tweet: tweet['lang'], tweets_data)
tweets['country'] = map(lambda tweet: tweet['place']['country'] if tweet['place'] != None else None, tweets_data)


tweets_by_lang = tweets['lang'].value_counts()
tweets_by_lang = tweets_by_lang.astype(int)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelsize=15)
ax.tick_params(axis='y', labelsize=10)
ax.set_xlabel('Languages', fontsize=15)
ax.set_ylabel('Number of tweets' , fontsize=15)
ax.set_title('Top 5 languages', fontsize=15, fontweight='bold')
tweets_by_lang.plot(ax=ax, kind='bar', color='red')
```

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: Can you show us `tweets_by_lang.head()` or a sample of its contents?

Comment: Is the Dataframe actually empty?